# convert a column in SQLView result to date and filter by a user specified date

Tags: sql, sql-view

can anyone help, i have a sql view with a Date column which is a varchar. When i run my statement below i get a conversion error

The [Planned Date/Time] column has some null values in the table so I have written a view like this

```
 select * from vwMDL where [Planned Date/Time] is not null and
                  Convert(date,[Planned Date/Time]) = '04/03/2015'
```

the above fails with conversion error. Do i select all non null values first and do a further select? If so will it cost me as i have lots of date returning in the view.

Thanks in advance. I am using SQL at the moment.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If `[Planned Date/Time]` is indexed, doing this will destroy performance.  As a rule of thumb, manipulate your parameters, not the columns being searched...  `AND [Planned Date/Time] = <Some code to change the string '04/03/2015' to match the string format used in your table>`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server.  You should use `try_convert()`:

```
select *
from vwMDL
where try_convert(date, [Planned Date/Time]) = '2015-04-03';
```

Note:  Use ISO/ANSI standard formats for your date constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
select * from vwMDL where [Planned Date/Time] is not null and
                 CONVERT(CHAR(20),CAST([Planned Date/Time] as DATETIME),101) = '04/03/2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what DB you are using, but all have some null fucntion that givea a null item some specific value (ISNULL, NVL, IFNULL, ...) so something like this should work.

```
select * 
from vwMDL 
where IsNull([Planned Date/Time], '01/01/1900') = '04/03/2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

if sql server then you can below query

```
select * from vwMDL 
 where Convert(date,COALESCE([Planned Date/Time],'04/03/1970'),103) = convert(date, '04/03/2015',103)
```

If Db my sql then

```
select * from vwMDL where STR_TO_DATE(COALESCE([Planned Date/Time],'04/03/1970')) =   STR_TO_DATE('14/02/2015', '%d/%m/%Y')
```